# Why using no backticks in phpmyadmin sql returns "This table does not contain a unique column"?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I have a table named "22_structures" with a primary key on "id".
In phpmyadmin, if I write (without backticks):

```
SELECT id, adress FROM 22_structures;
```

phpmyadmin says:

> Current selection does not contain a unique column

and I cannot edit a row in the result list. Then, if I write sql query (with backticks):

```
SELECT id,adress FROM `22_structures`;
```

phpmyadmin says nothing and I can well select and edit a row.

**Why ?**

**Is there a problem with the "22_" prefix of the table name ?**

Thanks a lot.

Comment: At least in general, ANSI standard SQL, an identifier is not allowed to start with a digit.

Comment: Yes, there is a problem. Standard table names start with letters, not digits. You can, however, start with a number by enclosing the whole table name in back ticks; if you do that, you'll need to do it everywhere you use the table.

Comment: Thank a lot to both of you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Table names are not allowed to start with digits. So backticks are required to escape such names. Renaming all my tables answered my question and solved the problem.